# Need to install glibc >= 2.14 on Wheezy

Tags: debian, glibc

I am trying to get [Protractor](https://github.com/juliemr/protractor) working for performing e2e angular testing, but protractor requires [Selenium](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/) which requires [ChromeDriver](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/) which requires `glibc` 2.14. My current development box is running Debian Wheezy which comes with `glibc` 2.13. I have read that switching over to Debian's unstable branch would provide access to `glib-2.14`, but from what I have heard unstable is pretty...unstable.

Is there any way I can upgrade `glibc` to 2.14 or 2.15 without the risk of breaking everything?  Or is it possible to switch back from the unstable Debian branch if things start to break?

```
12:15:22.784 INFO - Executing: [new session: {browserName=chrome}] at URL: /session)
12:15:22.796 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{browserName=chrome}]
/home/chris/projects/personal/woddy/client/selenium/chromedriver:     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by      /home/chris/projects/personal/woddy/client/selenium/chromedriver)
/home/chris/projects/personal/woddy/client/selenium/chromedriver: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/chris/projects/personal/woddy/client/selenium/chromedriver)
12:15:43.032 WARN - Exception thrown
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Comment: Where does it say that  ChromeDriver requires glibc 2.14? In general, high level packages don't have very narrow constraints on the C library. Does it say so somewhere in the documentation or the code, or is it simply listed as a dependency in some package? Be aware, if you are not already, that distribution packages may add overly strict dependencies for no good reason.

Comment: I added the terminal output above showing where 2.14 or 2.15 was required.  However all is working now.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You don't have to switch to the *unstable* to get glib >= 2.14. In fact, the testing branch (now stable, or Jessie) has glib-2.17 which you can pick just adding the testing repository and launching:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev=2.17-7
```

or,

```
sudo apt-get -t testing install libc6-dev
```

You can add the switch `--dry-run` to see what will being installed before hand. You can see the status of the glibc package in the [Debian Package Tracker System](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/eglibc) (Debian renamed eglibc package to simply [glibc](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/glibc) from Jessie onwards).

You can also just wait for Jessie [release on April 25](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2015/03/msg00016.html).

Comment: That did it. Following the debian instructions at http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-apt-get.en.html#s-default-version then running the second command you listed worked perfectly.  Thanks for the help. BTW I had it in my head that *unstable* was the next step up instead of testing.

Comment: Thanks, but perhaps you should also set-up apt-pinning as explained in
http://verahill.blogspot.ie/2014/03/562-pulling-in-glibc-214-from-testing.html

Comment: Neither of these worked for me. The first method produced `E: The value 'testing' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources` and the second `E: Version '2.17-7' for 'libc6-dev' was not found`

Comment: @SeanDeNigris "the testing branch has glib-2.17 which you can pick just **adding the testing repository**" you need to add the testing repositories to your sources.list and update the package lists.

Comment: @Braiam Thanks. I was interested in your approach because I'm updating [the installation instructions for Pharo](http://pharo.org/download). I liked it specifically because it didn't involve hacking config files, since we attract some non-programmer types. I guess maybe I could pin libc-only to testing...

Comment: @SeanDeNigris Actually, just wait for a while. Jessie (current testing) is about to be released.

Comment: That's good news! But, we're releasing Monday so I have to come up with the least-bad answer for the immediate future :/

Comment: This accepted solution really should have a warning. I followed it and  ended up with a "FrankenDebian": https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian

I then spent the next 2-3 hours fighting my way out of dependency hell and getting my system back to a stable Wheezy.

Comment: @Stacey "You can add the switch `--dry-run` to see what will being installed before hand." There was a method to verify what would happen before hand, you just need to test it. Also, it's presumed you know what you are doing and *have a good reason to do it*.

Comment: Debian.org explicitly mentions that this is a bad idea. Not everyone is a sysadmin. The OP asked for a safe , recommended solution, that *does not*  break anythong, and this solution does not meet any of those criteria.

Comment: @Stacey "My current **development** box is running Debian Wheezy"????

Comment: Since we're quoting things now. OP: "Is there any way I can upgrade glibc to 2.14 or 2.15 ***without the risk of breaking everything***?" Debian.org:"it's not a good idea to add repositories for other Debian releases.... This results in a system that is a ***broken mix of the two.***" How much more clear can I be? Hopefully people will read the comments before the taking this advice. I'm done.

Answer (score 23):

In my situation, the error appears when I try to run an application (compiled on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) using GLIBC_2.14 on Debian Wheezy (which installs glibc 2.13 by default).

I use a tricky way to run it, and get correct result:

1. Download [`libc6`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/libc6) and [`libc6-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libc6-dev) from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
2. Run `dpkg` command to install them into a directory (`/home/user/fakeroot/` for example):

   ```
   $ dpkg -x libc6-dev_2.15-0ubuntu10.6_amd64.deb /home/user/fakeroot/
   $ dpkg -x libc6_2.15-0ubuntu10.6_amd64.deb /home/user/fakeroot/
   ```
3. Run your command with specified `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

   ```
   $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/fakeroot/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ YOUR_COMMAND
   ```
4. My application only uses `memcpy()` from GLIBC_2.14, and it works.

   I don't know whether it will work successfully for other applications.

Comment: Thanks! These instructions allowed me to easily run Shaka Packager on Debian Wheezy. I'm wrapping my command in a bash script that looks like `exec env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/fakeroot/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ YOUR_COMMAND "$@"` so that the command is easily available without needing to specify LD_LIBRARY_PATH every time.

Comment: libc6 links are broken

Answer (score 1):

I guess there are several options for you to try out the unstable branch "safely":

- Virtualization
- [Chrooting](https://wiki.debian.org/chroot) whereby you choose an alternative directory as your apparent root directory. You can thus [create a file system image](http://freecode.com/articles/virtual-filesystem-building-a-linux-filesystem-from-an-ordinary-file) and manually install the required packages. This is a complicated process and it is made much easier in Debian's case using:
- [deboostrap](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap) which, to quote the Debian Wiki article at this link, is

  > a tool which will install a Debian base system into a subdirectory of another, already installed system. It doesn't require an installation CD, just access to a Debian repository.

  This is not to imply that `debootstrap` uses the chrooting technique; I'm not aware of its internal implementation.

Comment: I used the debootstrap tutorial and it was just what I needed:https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap

I followed the sid example but used jessie instead:
`debootstrap --arch amd64 jessie $MY_CHROOT http://http.debian.net/debian/`

Thank you!