# Skype Call Recorder in Debian 7.1: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found

Tags: debian, libraries, skype

I am trying to configure [Skype Call Recorder](http://atdot.ch/scr/download/) in Debian 7.1, running Skype 4.3.0.37.

Since there was no amd64 package for Debian, I am using `skype-call-recorder-ubuntu_0.10_amd64.deb`.
The installation seems to go smooth. However, once I run it, I get the following error:

```
skype-call-recorder: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by skype-call-recorder)
```

I have tried to locate a package for this library and I could not find which one should be. I have also tried with the Debian package, but it does not even run the installation properly.

Any idea what the issue could be? Where can I find the library? The closest information I have found is at http://www.pc-freak.net/blog/how-to-record-your-skype-calls-with-skype-call-recorder-on-debian-linux-install-skype-call-recorder-on-amd64-debian-squeeze-testingunstable-linux/ , but it seems there was not library dependency problem in this case.

Comment: The current stable glibc in Wheezy is 2.13-1.  See [glibc package details](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/glibc-2.13-1).  You need to [add 2.14](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85505/need-to-install-glibc-2-14-on-wheezy)

Comment: Hold on, upgrading the C library is a really bad idea in general.

Comment: @FaheemMitha, I agree but he asked how to do it...

Comment: You already have the library: it's `libc.so.6`. But your version is too old: you have 2.13 but the binary you installed requires at least 2.14 (and it's badly made: it doesn't declare its dependencies properly). I suggest [compiling](http://atdot.ch/scr/compiling/) from source — though I don't know where the source of the latest version is.

Comment: It could be interesting to find out what glibc 2.14 feature is so vital to this piece of software... Maybe previous versions of Skype Call Recording worked under glibc 2.13x: they might still be available for download somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I did not want to mess with the libraries, therefore I tried the suggestion of @john-wh-smith:

> It could be interesting to find out what glibc 2.14 feature is so vital to this piece of software... Maybe previous versions of Skype Call Recording worked under glibc 2.13x: they might still be available for download somewhere.

Version 0.8 works perfectly with the old version of the C library (concretely for this specific case I used skype-call-recorder-ubuntu_0.8_amd64.deb).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the debian experimental repository to your /etc/sources.list
from there you need to download and install glibc 2.17, this can be a bad idea if you don't know what you're doing though as running unstable software can be dangerous, so be weary.