# CentOS, using different glibc version

Tags: linux, centos, glibc

I followed this question: [How to update glibc to 2.14 in CentOS 6.5](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176489/how-to-update-glibc-to-2-14-in-centos-6-5)

Did all the steps mentioned, everything is installed as it should be. However when I check the version, it still is:

[image]

I am using Cloudera VM for Hadoop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers to the other question are to install 2.14 alongside alongside 2.12, not to upgrade to it.

If you are using 2.14 to compile something then you'll need to set the path to its libraries in your compile options.

CentOS 6 and its minor releases are EOL at the end of November of this year so it's best to replace that system with CentOS 7 or CentOS 8 as soon as possible. That would also give you a more recent version of `glibc` anyway.