# /lib64/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.14' not found in Redhat 6.5, for running a software in non-desktop version of Linux

Tags: command-line, rhel, glibc

Whenever I try to run a software, my red hat 6.5 Linux server displays

```
grok :/lib64/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by grok)
```

(grok is a file which I use need to run my simulation models)

I tried using `yum -y update glibc`, but it shows the following message.

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
```

Can anyone please suggest the steps of where and what to download and install, so that I can run my simulation models. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update glibc to 2.14 in CentOS 6.5](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176489/how-to-update-glibc-to-2-14-in-centos-6-5)

Comment: The solution is for CentOS but will for on RHEL too. Btw. your RHEL machine is not subscribed so installing/updating using `yum` won't work (but glibc 2.14 is not available anyway). Also CentOS/RHEL 6 end of life was last month, you should upgrade to 7 or 8 soon.

Comment: Hello @Vojtech Trefny, I tried executing all the commands step by step, but it resulted in the following error, kindly assist, please

../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.14

checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

checking for gcc... no

checking for cc... no

checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/home/shankark/glibc_install/glibc-2.14/build':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details