# GLIBC_2.14 and C compiler missing from Centos 6.7

Tags: linux, centos, gcc, glibc

I have came across a situation today on my CentOS 6.7 VM, where I'm trying install any package via yum I'm getting the below given error:

```
yum install gcc

There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

  /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/lib/libssl.so.10)

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 23 2015, 15:22:56) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

I got the compilation steps for 'GLIBC_2.14' from the below given link:

[How to update glibc to 2.14 in CentOS 6.5](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176489/how-to-update-glibc-to-2-14-in-centos-6-5)

But gcc is not already installed on my VM. So I am getting the following error on the configure step:

```
../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.14

checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/dir/glibc-2.14/build':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

I can't use yum to install gcc. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Why are you using an insecure, unsupported OS version?

Comment: Your `libc` seems to be broken, or your version of `yum` is incompatible with the installed `libc` version. You could try installing `libc` from an rpm file. Since Centos 6 is not supported anymore, you may have to find it on http://vault.centos.org. Depending on your situation, trying to fix the problem may not be worth the hassle, and you may be better off just installing Centos 7.

Comment: Your question lacks details on what has *lead* to this situation. In all probability, you did unsupported stuff like self-compiled newer OpenSSL version. Just reverse what you did.

Comment: Using new libc versions in old Linux distros is quite complicated and oftentimes impossible due to libc requiring new kernel versions. Also your distro has long been unsupported and unsafe to use in any network environment.

Comment: It’s not even the latest release of the EOL CentOS 6, which is 6.10.